# How is this image on Reddit's page displayed?

Tags: html, frontend

For this [Reddit page](https://www.reddit.com/r/ImpeachDonaldTrump/), how is the "a snoo with balloons" picture displayed there? It's clearly not a direct image and I have no clue of which part of this page's source code is responsible for displaying or generating it there.

[image: snoo with balloons picture]

Comment: It’s a background image. Just inspect the element.

Comment: Could be a background image?

Comment: If you are using chrome press F12 & you can use develper tools to inpect it with Styles Tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a background URL from the `<div class = "footer-parent">` 
(http://c.thumbs.redditmedia.com/UNcO-h_QcS9PD-Gn.jpg). Just inspect the element using the browser and the background property should appear as:

```
background: url(//c.thumbs.redditmedia.com/UNcO-h_QcS9PD-Gn.jpg) 49% 0% no-repeat;
```